# Редактирование содержимого MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно редактировать содержимое через форму, которая внизу показана, в окно логин: вводишь username из таблицы, который нужно редактировать, у окно редактировать логин: вводишь свое значение и меняется логин тот, который вписали выше, в этом коде получается только отредактировать первый username в таблице и только через окно логин:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '$username'");
}

$ath = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
if ($ath) {
    // Определяем таблицу и заголовок
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td>user_id</td><td>логин</td><td>пароль</td><td>имя</td><td>email</td></tr>";
    // Так как запрос возвращает несколько строк, применяем цикл
    while ($author = mysql_fetch_array($ath)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $author['user_id'] . " </td><td>" . $author['username'] . " </td><td>" . $author['password'] . "
                &nbsp </td><td>" . $author['first_name'] . " </td><td>" . $author['email'] . "
                &nbsp </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "<p><b>Error: " . mysql_error() . "</b><p>";
    exit();
}
?>
```

-

```
<form action="" method="POST">логин:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>редактировать логин:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="корректировать">
    <br>
    <a href="index.php">вернутия на страницу</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Ты пытаешся изменить username у всех записей таблицы users. Нормальное решение — использовать **уникальный идентификатор** записи, например первичный ключ (обычно с именем id). Типа: `UPDATE username=:username FROM users WHERE id=:id` Этот id можешь держать в форме в `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123">`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_POST['username'][0]) && isset($_POST['username'][1])) {
    $old_name = $_POST['username'][0]; //текущий логин
    $new_name = $_POST['username'][1]; //новый логин
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '$new_name' WHERE `username`='$old_name'");
}
```

и форму сделать так

```
<form action="" method="POST">логин:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username[]">
    <br>редактировать логин:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username[]">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="корректировать">
    <br>
    <a href="index.php">вернуться на страницу</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

А не проще сделать name="oldusername" и "newusername"?